# Netsuite saved search Trim

Tags: validation, trim, netsuite

I have a field defined in custom record as data type Rich Text. For most of the part the data coming to that field is Text like 445F1 or 445D9, but occasionally the data comes into it as 44500 and also as '450'.

I created a saved search to find all the values for the field which are not 5 digits in length to give me all erroneous values like '455E1 or '455E2' which are 6 and 7 digits respectively (including the single quotes).

The problem is when the length is still 5 digits and the records are erroneous like 44500 or '450'.

To fix this I tried to create another filter in saved search as

```
Formula(Numeric)
To_number(Trim Both "'" From {myfield}) is greater than or equal to 1
```

But I keep on getting error message saying there is a syntax problem in my filter:

> Your formula has an error in it. It could resolve to the wrong datatype, use an unknown function, or have a syntax error. Please go back, correct the formula, and re-submit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused because '455E1 or '455E2' are five digits (not 6 and 7) and '450' is not five digits. Is it possible to clarify what you're trying to filter?

Comment: So the field will have ' . So '455E1 is 6 digit and '455E2' is 7 digit. I am trying to remove ' from the field (from both front and end). Does this helps

Comment: Oh I see -- the single quotes are included in the strings. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This is the error I keep on getting "Your formula has an error in it. It could resolve to the wrong datatype, use an unknown function, or have a syntax error. Please go back, correct the formula, and re-submit."

Comment: And this is the formula ** Formula (Numeric) is greater than or equal to 1 TO_NUMBER(TRIM(BOTH "'" FROM {custrecord258}))   Or**

Comment: You might want to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34026130/edit) that information into your question. I tried to edit it for you, but I'm not sure I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

> Formula(Numeric)
>   To_number(Trim Both "'" From {myfield}) is greater than or equal to 1
>
> What am I doing wrong?

Remember : *`{myfield}`* is not a Table. So you just can't run a query with `From` clause here.

To get it work you should use something like this :

```
Formula(Numeric)
LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM({myfield}))) not equal to 5
```

But this formula will failed in case the string has any character formatting.(Won't work for rich formatted text).

I would recommend to try some other workaround in such scenario to get your job done.
One possible solution would be to create a dynamic field and set a formula to calculate the length of the string.

```
 LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM({myfield})))
```

On the saved search you can directly search for the length and filter out erroneous data.

Comment: My Problem is to trim the single quote from my field from both sides and count the length of the field to be 5. if it is not 5 then it is problem.

Answer (score 0):

> So I added couple of filters to achieve this.

```
Formula (Text)  SUBSTR({myfield}, -1, 1) starts with '
```

*This tell me if the last character of my field is single quote*

```
Formula (Text)  SUBSTR({myfield}, 1, 1) starts with '
```

*This tells me if the first character of my field is single quote*
and

```
Formula (Numeric) TO_NUMBER({myfield})  is greater than 100
```

*This tells me if for some reason the instead of text I have number in my field.*

> It is a workaround but does the trick

Comment: Cool ! If this does the work for you, then you could probably accept your own answer. :) And thanks for sharing it.